# I need help to unravel this proposition, I'm stuck because I don't understand what happens when multiplying the adjacent matrix $k$ times.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $L$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph. For all pair of vertices $v_i , v_j $, the L input k (i, j) of the kth power of L represents the number of walks of length k between these vertices.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic graph theory result which procedes by induction on $k$. Let $G$ be our graph, with associated adjacency matrix $A$. Our claim is that $A^k(i,j) = $ the total number of walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ which use **exactly** $k$ edges.

**Base Case:** $k = 1$

The number of walks of length $1$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$ is just $1$ is they are adjacent and $0$ if not, which is precisely how $A = A^1$ is defined.

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Suppose the result holds for $A^{k-1}$

Now lets think about all possible $k$-length walks from any $v_i$ to $v_j$ (there may be none, but it does not matter). We can break up such walks into a $k-1$ length walk from $v_i$ to $v_h$ for any $v_h$ and a $1$ length walk from $v_h$ to $v_j$. Let $N(v_j)$ denote the neighborhood set of $v_j$. Then we have that the number of length $k$ walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ is given by
$$
\sum_{v_h \in N(v_j)}\text{the number of $k-1$ length walks from $v_i$ to $v_h$}
$$
By the inductive hypothesis, this is precisely equal to
$$
\sum_{v_h \in N(v_j)} A^{k-1}(i,h)
$$
If $G$ has $n$ vertices, we can rewrite this as
$$
\sum_{h = 1}^nA^{k-1}(i,h)A(h,j)
$$
because $A(h,j)$ will be $1$ if $v_h\in N(v_j)$ and $0$ otherwise by the base case. This exactly how we define matrix multiplication, so we have
$$
\sum_{h = 1}^nA^{k-1}(i,h)A(h,j) = A^k(i,j)
$$
as desired.